# Canvas, make corner with entry data

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

I need to make app which take parameters from inputs and make figure with one corner which should be cut for quantity of pixels depended from entry data for corner. I already make function which takes parameters and make figure but I don't know how to make that angle, if somebody meet before case like this, please help me. Angle which take radius like parameter should be 90 degrees and radius mean pixels how much should be deep.

[image]

```
    <div class="solution__wrapper">
    <canvas id="detail" width="1000" height="600"></canvas>
</div>

<div id="app">
  <div class="control">
    <button id="rotateZ">Rotate</button>
    <span> Length: </span>
    <input id="heightInput" placeholder="Length:" type="text" />
    <span> Width: </span>
    <input id="widthInput" placeholder="Width:" type="text" />
    <span> Radius angle: </span>
    <input id="rightAngleInput" placeholder="Radius:" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>




  let detail = {
  length: 350,
  width: 250,
  lt: { radius: 0 },
  lb: { radius: 0 },
  rt: { radius: 50 },
  rb: { radius: 0 }
};

const app = document.getElementById("app");
const heightInput = document.getElementById("heightInput");
const widthInput = document.getElementById("widthInput");
const leftAngleInput = document.getElementById("rightAngleInput");
const rotateZ = document.getElementById("rotateZ");

(() => {

const myDetail = document.getElementById("detail");
const context = myDetail.getContext("2d");

  const roundRect = (x, y, w, h, radius) => {

    let r = x + w;
    let b = y + h;
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle="black";
    context.lineWidth="2";
    context.moveTo(x+radius, y);
    context.lineTo(r-radius, y);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(r, y, r, y);
    context.lineTo(r, y+h-radius);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(r, b, r, b);
    context.lineTo(x+radius, b);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x, b, x, b);
    context.lineTo(x, y+radius);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x+radius, y);
    context.stroke();

  }
  roundRect(400, 100, detail.width, detail.length, 50);

  let rotation = 0;
  let targetRotate = 90;

  rotateZ.addEventListener("click", () => {

    let newLength = +heightInput.value;
    let newWidth = +widthInput.value;
    let newRadRight = +leftAngleInput.value;

    detail.length = newLength;
    detail.width = newWidth;
    detail.rt.radius = newRadRight;

    rotation = (rotation + targetRotate) % 360;
    myDetail.style.transform = `rotate(${rotation}deg)`;

    context.clearRect(0, 0, myDetail.width, myDetail.height);

    roundRect(400, 100, detail.width, detail.length, detail.rt.radius);
  });
})();
```

Comment: I'm unsure on what you are looking for. Do you want to draw that rectangle with an inset curve on the bottom right corner, of radius 80?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The draw function to create the shape you're looking for will look very similar to the `roundedRect()` function you have already.

Instead of doing `quadraticCurveTo()` at each corner, only do it at the bottom right corner. You will also need to change the position of the control point of the curve.

The code for that function would look like this:

```js
function draw() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  const drawDetail = (x, y, w, h, rad) => {
    const r = x + w;
    const b = y + h;

    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.lineWidth = "2";
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    context.lineTo(r, y);
    context.lineTo(r, b - rad);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(r - rad, b - rad, r - rad, b);
    context.lineTo(x, b);
    context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
  };

  drawDetail(0, 0, 250, 350, 80);
}

draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="src/index.js">
    </script>

    <canvas id='canvas' width='400' height='600'></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note: if the cut needs to be part of the circle, use `context.arc(r, b, rad, -Math.PI * .5, -Math.PI, true);` instead of `quadraticCurveTo`.

Comment: But how to make angle 90 degrees inside ?

Comment: Replace `context.quadraticCurveTo(r - rad, b - rad, r - rad, b);` with 2 lines `context.lineTo(r - rad, b - rad); ` `context.lineTo(r - rad, b);`

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I want. You real pro man =)